# Using grep in while loop

Tags: shell, grep

Is it possible to go trough the results of grep in using a shell script like this:

```
while read line ; do
    ...
done < grep ...
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work? What are the alternatives?

thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do? grep for something from each line read in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you were trying to use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution):

```
lines=5
while read line ; do
    let ++lines
    echo "$lines $line" # Number each line
    # Other operations on $line and $lines
done < <(grep ...)
echo "Total: $lines lines"
```

Provided `grep` actually returns some output lines, the result should look like this:

```
6: foo
7: bar
Total: 7 lines
```

This is slightly different from `grep ... | while ...`: In the former, `grep` is run in a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell), while in the latter the `while` loop is in a subshell. This is usually only relevant if you want to keep some state from within the loop - In that case you should use the first form.

On the other hand, if you write

```
lines=5
grep ... | while read line ; do
    let ++lines
    echo "$lines $line" # Number each line
    # Other operations on $line and $lines
done
echo "Total: $lines lines"
```

the result would be:

```
6: foo
7: bar
Total: 5 lines
```

Ouch! The counter is passed to the subshell (the second part of the pipe), but it's not returned to the parent shell.

Comment: so this can be used to process each line individually, but i cannot for example use a counter in the loop? Can you explain the syntax?

Answer (score 4):

`grep` is a command but `done < grep` is telling the shell to use the *file* named grep as the input.  You need something like:

```
grep ... | while read line ; do
    ...
done
```